# Mensaje de error por el tipo de variable al aplicar CASE en un campo de una tabla (ORACLE)

Tags: oracle

Tengo parte de una consulta para un diccionario de datos en Oracle:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de cambiar el valor del campo `DATA_DEFAULT` en caso sea `null`. Cuando hago la consulta con el campo que está comentando (flecha azul) me sale el el siguiente resultado en el campo `DATA_DEFAULT`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando lo hago con la línea indicada con la flecha en rojo me sale el siguiente mensaje de error haciendo referencia a la variable que resalto de amarillo, y si lo puse en ese lugar es por que en caso no sea `null` quiero que me devuelva el mismo valor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen, lo que quiero es que en el resultado de la consulta no me salga `null` en el campo `DATA_DEFAULT` sino un espacio vacío (' '). He intentado "castear" la variable después del `else` sin éxito, se agradece cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: Bueno, qué tipo de datos es la columna original `DATA_DEFAULT`?

Comment: Me faltó copiar parte del mensaje de error que dice: "uso no válido del tipo de dato LONG"

Comment: Ok, pero me gustaría asegurar cuál es el tipo de dato de la columna `DATA_DEFAULT`

Comment: Como el error indica, `data_default` es de tipo `LONG` y el espacio vacío es de tipo `CHAR`. Los dos lados del `CASE` necesitan devolver el mismo tipo. En este caso, no estoy seguro si hay una manera conveniente de hacerlo, porque `LONG` es un tipo obsoleto que no es fácil usar.  Francamente, yo optaría por dejar el `null` tal cual.

Comment: @Lamak: Solo porque estoy al tanto de su pregunta anterior, sé que se refiere a la columna `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.DATA_DEFAULT` que es de tipo `LONG`, un tipo anticuado que es el equivalente pobre de `CLOB`.

Comment: @Lamak, he visto la documentación de Oracle y dice que es de tipo LONG el campo en cuestión.

Comment: no se debiera ocupar `nvl(X.data_default,' ') DATA_DEFAULT` ?

Comment: @amenadiel: En efecto, lo que propones es equivalente, pero tristemente, produciría el mismo error.  El problema es la conversión de tipos, y este problema es el mismo usando `CASE` o `NVL`.